# Add multiple line into one in shell script linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file in linux called 1.txt with multiple lines and need to merge every three lines

into one line.I have mentioned the output below and need  to know how to do that

```
[xxx@c0040229 ~]$ cat 1.txt
c0043726.xxx.xx
50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco    
200K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043725.xxx.xx
50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco
196K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043724.xxx.xx
50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco
92K,/opt/tibco/scripts
```

**Out put should be**

```
c0043726.xxx.xx,50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco,200K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043725.xxx.xx,50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco,196K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043724.xxx.xx,50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco,92K,/opt/tibco/scripts
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: First ask a question. The only question in what you've typed is "can somebody help me". Post the input and your expected output. Then mention what you've tried so that people can offer constructive advice.

Comment: I have edited the question with input as in "cat 1.txt" and out put as  c0043726.xxx.xx,50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco,200K,/opt/tibco/scripts

c0043725.xxx.xx,50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco,196K,/opt/tibco/scripts

c0043724.xxx.xx,50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco,92K,/opt/tibco/scripts

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve what you want with the paste command:

```
cat 1.txt | paste -d',' - - -
```

Comment: [xxx@c0040229 ~]$ cat 1.txt | paste -d',' - - -
,200K,/opt/tibco/scriptsbco
,196K,/opt/tibco/scriptsibco
,92K,/opt/tibco/scriptsibco

Comment: it is different output

Comment: Your whole command should be just: cat 1.txt | paste -d',' - - -

Comment: It looks like your file might have Windows' line endings. In that case, could you try this? cat 1.txt | sed 's/\r//g' | paste -d',' - - -

Answer (score 1):

Use the `paste` command and give it stdin (`-`) as input three times like this:

```
$ cat 1.txt 
c0043726.xxx.xx
50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco
200K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043725.xxx.xx
50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco
196K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043724.xxx.xx
50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco
92K,/opt/tibco/scripts
$ paste -d, - - - < 1.txt 
c0043726.xxx.xx,50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco,200K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043725.xxx.xx,50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco,196K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043724.xxx.xx,50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco,92K,/opt/tibco/scripts
```

Paste is normally used to 'paste -- merge corresponding or subsequent lines of files', and if you feed it with stdin three times, you get the desired effet.

Comment: for me output is always below . where is the problem ?                                          [xxx@c0040229 ~]$ paste -d, - - - < 1.txt
,200K,/opt/tibco/scriptsbco
,196K,/opt/tibco/scriptsibco
,92K,/opt/tibco/scriptsibco

Comment: is the file being transferred from a Windows computer to a UNIX computer or vice versa?

Comment: what does `cat -e 1.txt` output?

Comment: Thanks For all you help .There is strange character ^M comming in 1.txt , which preventing me to slove this issue.

[xxx@c0040229 ~]$ cat -v 1.txt | xargs -L 1| sed -e 's/ /,/g'
c0043726.itcs.hp.com^M
50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco^M
200K,/opt/tibco/scripts^M
c0043725.itcs.hp.com^M
50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco^M
196K,/opt/tibco/scripts^M
c0043724.itcs.hp.com^M
50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco^M
92K,/opt/tibco/scripts^M

Now it is ok after removing after ^M with sed command .This creature only visible by cat -v command. Thanks Again for your help

Answer (score 0):

A simple script can also accomplish what you want. Reading your datafile and then merging 3 lines into one. Below the output is just echoed to the screen for illustration, but you can simply redirect each `echo` statement to a file using the `>>` append operator. This uses a case statement and simple counter. You can save a line or two using `$cnt % 3` modulo operator to test for the 3rd line. Here is a short example:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0

while IFS=$'\n' read -a line || test -n "$line"; do 
    ((cnt++))
    case "$cnt" in
      [1-2] ) echo -n "$line,";;
      3     ) echo "$line"; cnt=0;;
    esac
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ ./3lines.sh dat/3line.dat
c0043726.xxx.xx,50G,3.6G,44G,8%,/opt/tibco,200K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043725.xxx.xx,50G,9.5G,38G,21%,/opt/tibco,196K,/opt/tibco/scripts
c0043724.xxx.xx,50G,1.6G,46G,4%,/opt/tibco,92K,/opt/tibco/scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
awk 'NR % 3 !=0 {printf $0;printf " "} NR % 3 ==0 {print " "}' fileName.txt